# How to add hindi character search in preg_match_all() in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

We can know it is for English characters like,

if( preg_match_all('/something/', $any, $match)

But can we also use for hindi character??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used it in my code itself

```
/[^\p{Zs}\p{P}]*?ह[^\p{Zs}\p{P}]*/u
```

Modifier `/u` is for unicode support.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU8bD3/1)

for **your code** do it like this

```
$any = 'तरह के लाभ मिलते हैं';
$searchword = 'ह';

preg_match_all('/[^\p{Zs}\p{P}]*?'.$searchword.'[^\p{Zs}\p{P}]*/u', $any, $match);

print_r($match);
```

**output will be**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => तरह
            [1] => हैं
        )

)
```

Comment: If i need English and Hindi both language character like    "  ENGLISH CHARACTER, HINDI CHARACTER "   In this case how i perform regex??